# SQL Server foreign key window issue for newly created EF Code first table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

I don't know if anyone face this issue or it's just something else.

I am using a EF code-first architecture.

Here is my first class :

```
public class PerformanceSurchargeGeneralSettings : FullAuditedEntity
{
    public int PerformanceID { get; set; }
    public Performance Performance { get; set; }

    public int SurchargeId { get; set; }
    public Surcharges Surcharge { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the second class:

```
public class Surcharges : FullAuditedEntity
{
    public  string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PerformanceSurchargeGeneralSettings> PerformanceSurchargeGeneralSettings{ get; set; }
}
```

Everything works fine, I can add migration, update my database but if I go to table and check for foreign key reference, I can't see primary key table. See this screenshot here:

[image]

I am not able to find newly added table that is `Surcharge` in the dropdown of primary key table.

And if I execute `SP_help` for this table, I can find all foreign keys, see the screenshot:

[image]

I don't understand where exactly the issue is ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H,

Change your classes as below;

```
[Table("PerformanceSurchargeGeneralSettings")]
public class PerformanceSurchargeGeneralSetting : FullAuditedEntity
{
    [ForeignKey("PerformanceId")]
    public virtual Performance Performance { get; set; }
    public int PerformanceId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SurchargeId")]
    public virtual Surcharge Surcharge { get; set; }
    public int SurchargeId { get; set; }    
}
```

---

```
[Table("Surcharges")]
public class Surcharge : FullAuditedEntity
{
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PerformanceSurchargeGeneralSetting> PerformanceSurchargeGeneralSettings{ get; set; }
}
```

---

My advises

- Use singular names for classes. Surcharges => Surcharge.
- Give **MaxLength** to string properties.
- Use the same case for all Id fields. PerformanceID => PerformanceId. (like you did for SurchageId).
- Add **virtual** key when you want to load data with lazy loading.

Comment: I will give a try, give me few hours

Comment: @aaron: not checked yey, because my functinality is working fine, and for some time i don't want to disturb it..

Comment: happy coding ;)